# Adding button to collapsibleset header

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Using jQuery mobile 1.4.5, I'm trying to place a button inside the header bar of a collapsible set like so:

```
<div data-role="collapsibleset" data-content-theme="a" data-iconpos="left" id="street_listing" class="ui-collapsible-set ui-group-theme-inherit ui-corner-all">
    <div data-role="collapsible" class="ui-collapsible ui-collapsible-inset ui-corner-all ui-collapsible-themed-content ui-first-child ui-last-child ui-collapsible-collapsed">
        <h3 id="street_name" class="ui-collapsible-heading ui-collapsible-heading-collapsed">

             <a href="#" class="ui-collapsible-heading-toggle ui-btn ui-btn-icon-left ui-btn-inherit ui-icon-plus">Street name
                 <a href="#remove_street_button" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline remove_street" street="street" id="remove_street">Remove</a>
                 <span class="ui-collapsible-heading-status"> click to expand contents</span>
             </a>
        </h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem is that clicking the button doesn't register. It only opens and closes the header bar. Here is the function I'm trying to trigger when the button is clicked:

```
$(function() {
  $(document).on('click', ".remove_from_group", (function() {
    //do stuff
  }))  
});
```

Complicating matters is the collapsibleset get injected into the page dynamically via an ajax call.

Answer (score 1):

Add a button in a `<span>` inside the collapsible heading like this (give it a class too, like 'delbtn' below--you can float it right in css if you want--see the fiddle at bottom)

```
 <div data-role="collapsible">
    <h3>Section 1 <span class='delbtn '>
     <a href="#" data-role="button" data-inline="true" 
       class="ui-btn ui-mini ui-icon-delete ui-btn-icon-left">Remove</a>
     </span>
    </h3>
```

Then use this code to remove it on click

```
 $(".delbtn").click(function(){
    var section = $(this).closest(".ui-collapsible")
    section.remove()
});
```

Here is a working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bhkm56jv/)

Comment: Hmm, the click is still not registering for me. Clicking on it just expands/collapses they body. The only difference between my code and yours is that the collapsible set header and the button are injected into the page after an ajax call. Not sure why that would make a difference. And my button works fine when it is not in the header. Weird. I'll keep looking. 

Thanks.

Comment: I can put an onclick() bit of javascript code directly into the span tag and that is registering. Very weird.

Comment: Yeah, so throwing this into the `span` tag did the trick:

`onclick="\$(function() { var section = \$('#remove_street_street_id').closest('.ui-collapsible'); section.remove();});"`

No idea why putting something similar in the `<script>` section in the header has no effect.